# CORDA 3.1 Roadmap

Tags: corda

Let me know if any of you have the roadmap from R3 about the following features? I believe that they stated that these will be the features of commercial product, but I don't see any of them in their release.

I will appreciate the help.

1. Pluggable State Database (It supports only H2 database, do you have any documentation for any of commercial database such as Oracle Database
2. Pluggable  Middleware Messaging System( it supports embedded activemq artemis currenlty , is there any plan to provide the support for RabbitMQ or IBM MQ as the standalone server.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming enterprise version of Corda does indeed include the capability to use commercial databases (eg Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, Postgresql) to store ledger data. You can see some references to it in the blog posts [here](https://medium.com/corda/high-availability-for-r3-corda-nodes-bbdc6d92a156) and [here](https://medium.com/corda/peer-to-peer-enterprise-blockchain-networking-with-the-corda-firewall-4f6a427ebd97).

Ability to use 3rd party middleware messaging systems is a longer-term feature - we are considering this but there are currently no concrete plans to implement it.